# Recover passwords with a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, passwords, documentation

So here is my problem: I would like to create an extension that would display my saved passwords in the browser. I have read the documentation but I don't see how to do it, is there a function that does that ? I'm a beginner and it's the first time I read an official documentation, it's complicated for me to understand. Here is what I did for the moment I just wanted to display the cookies of all my sites and delete some data I'm also testing some features I would also like if possible to have external sources that explains well enough how to use the API of chrome thank you in advance. I think I understood how to use the manifest just the code in the background that I have trouble understanding.

```
//background.js
console.clear();
var callback = function () {
    // Do something clever here once data has been removed.
};

chrome.browsingData.remove({
    "origins": ["https://odysee.com/"]
}, {
    "cacheStorage": true,
    "cookies": true,
    "fileSystems": true,
    "indexedDB": true,
    "localStorage": true,
    "serviceWorkers": true,
    "webSQL": true
    }, callback);

function logCookies(cookies) {
    for (cookie of cookies) {
        console.log(`Domain: ${cookie.domain}`);
        console.log(`Name: ${cookie.name}`);
        console.log(`Value: ${cookie.value}`);
        console.log(`Persistent: ${!cookie.session}`);
    }
}
  
let gettingAll = chrome.cookies.getAll({});
gettingAll.then(logCookies);//
// console.log(chrome.cookies.getAll({}));
```